# border-left with color overrides border-radius?

Tags: css, border

I have a table td with CSS properties:

```
border-radius: 4px; 
border-left: 5px solid red;
```

I want the left border to be rounded and red. But, it seems like the border radius does not come up on the left side when I try to give it a color.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just swapping the ordering will fix this:

```
border-left: 5px solid red;
border-radius: 4px;
```

This is because `border-left:` will set everything to the default values, including the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Because your border-left is less than the radius. if you gove border radius 4 pc and border-left 5 px. It will not visible to you.. Make your radius greater than border-left.
For example

```
<div class="a">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur ea dicta perferendis, error qui, nisi labore cupiditate aspernatur et, recusandae nemo itaque aliquid velit sint voluptatum alias hic amet omnis.
</div>

.a{
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

[image]